# Why Does My CSS Not Render ?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a thin border. Simple. My code will not render it. In order to give it the maximum specificity I placed temporarily in a page element:

```
<div style="max-width: 100%; position: relative;border-radius: 4px; border-color: #ddd; border:thin; background-color: #ffffff ;">
```

Regardless of anything I do,the border will not render. Everything else renders. If I put the background colour to red, it renders fine. Not the border.

So, looking into Chrome developer tools I see that the border width is described as 0px, which makes no sense. However if I expand that I see my value of 1px.

[image: a screenshot]

There are no other inherited values in the CSS which would appear to override my border. So I am totally confused.

Many thanks !

Comment: You haven't actually set the width of the border therefore it defaults to 0, try border: 1px solid #ddd; make sure the element is actually rendering (play around with the height) and maybe make it display:block;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the style for your border.

```
border-style: solid;
```

Also, using

```
border: thin;
```

overrides any previous values you've set, use

```
border-width: thin;
```

instead.

Comment: It's best to get used to "border: 1px solid black" syntax.

Comment: @Senthe Usually, but not always, using these properties separately can be very useful in combining cascading inheritance.